# Refactor a Function that may Return a Return

Tags: vb.net, refactoring, return

I was working through some old code in a very large function and I needed to write a new function to be called a couple times from the old function. This new function will provide information as to if I need to `Return` early in the old function.

My question is what is a more straight forward or better way to accomplish whats below? How do I refactor this?

I guess another way to ask is..What is a better way to `Return` a `Return`?

```
Public Class ExampleClass

''' <summary>
''' This function calls another function
''' </summary>
''' <returns></returns>
Protected Overridable Function FunctionOne() As Boolean
    FunctionOne = False
    Dim lobjOne, lobjTwo, lobjThree As Object
    Dim lblnExit As Boolean = False
    '
    ' Some logic here (manipulates/gets objects)
    '
    lblnExit = FunctionTwo(lobjOne, lobjTwo)
    If lblnExit Then
        Return lblnExit
    ElseIf lobjOne.This.That > 2 Then
        Return lblnExit
    End If
    '
    ' Some more logic here (manipulates objects)
    '
    lblnExit = FunctionTwo(lobjOne, lobjTwo)
    If lblnExit Then
        Return lblnExit
    ElseIf lobjOne.This.That > 2 Then
        Return lblnExit
    End If
    '
    ' Performing some final actions
    '
End Function


''' <summary>
''' This function is called by FunctionOne Multiple Times
''' </summary>
''' <returns></returns>
Protected Overridable Function FunctionTwo(ByVal pobjOne As Object, ByVal pobjTwo As Object) As Boolean
    FunctionTwo = False
    '
    ' Performing some long complicated checking that either Returns true or exits
    '
End Function

End Class
```

Comment: perhaps this question belongs to here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could avoid the duplicated conditional logic by encapsulating the `FunctionTwo` call and result checking in a lambda expression:

```
Protected Overridable Function FunctionOne() As Boolean
    FunctionOne = False
    Dim lobjOne, lobjTwo, lobjThree As Object
    Dim lblnExit As Boolean = False
    Dim functionTwoEx =
        Function()
            lblnExit = FunctionTwo(lobjOne, lobjTwo)
            Return lblnExit OrElse lobjOne.This.That > 2
        End Function
    '
    ' Some logic here (manipulates/gets objects)
    '
    If functionTwoEx() Then
        Return lblnExit
    End If
    '
    ' Some more logic here (manipulates objects)
    '
    If functionTwoEx() Then
        Return lblnExit
    End If
    '
    ' Performing some final actions
    '
End Function
```

Whether that is better would depend on how complex your actual checks are, and how meaningful you can make the `functionTwoEx` name.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the conditional logic a bit.

```
lblnExit = FunctionTwo(lobjOne, lobjTwo)
If lblnExit Or lobjOne.This.That > 2 Then
    Return lblnExit
End If
```